# pg_upgrade from Postgresql-15 to Postgresql-16 fails with postgis installed

Tags: postgresql, archlinux, postgresql-16

I'm upgrading from Postgres 15 to 16 on Arch using the [default documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PostgreSQL#Upgrading_PostgreSQL). When I reach the pg_upgrade section:

```
pg_upgrade -b /opt/pgsql-15/bin -B /usr/bin -d /var/lib/postgres/olddata -D /var/lib/postgres/data
```

Then I get a "failure" exit. When I check the pg_upgrade_output.d log file I found an error related to PostGIS path:

```
command: "/usr/bin/pg_dump" --host /var/lib/postgres --port 50432 --username postgres --schema-only --quote-all-identifiers --binary-upgrade --format=custom  --file="/var/lib/postgres/data/pg_upgrade_output.d/20231207T105131.842/dump/pg_upgrade_dump_16385.custom" 'dbname=linuxbox_db' >> "/var/lib/postgres/data/pg_upgrade_output.d/20231207T105131.842/log/pg_upgrade_dump_16385.log" 2>&1
pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-3": No such file or directory
```

Is it something on my system or a bug in the pg_upgrade code?

Comment: No there is failure to read the docs [pg_upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html): *5. Install extension shared object files*. [Postgis upgrade](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/upgrades.html): *37.1.2.2. pg_upgrade*

Comment: You must have PostGIS installed for both v15 and v16. It looks like you didn't install the software for v15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because I needed to rebuild the postgis library after installing v16 and before running the pg_upgrade.

If someone else ends up having trouble upgrading on Arch, here is a summary of the steps I followed:

- check the modifications to postgis-old-upgrade for the latest postgresql version! (check AUR page)
- Update all the db to current collation version. Get into psql from postgresql account and it will tell you the command to use or run the script https://gist.github.com/AlfredoRamos/63def9c77081a6dba7db38d3b0669cef
- Stop postgresql from syscntl

> sudo systemctl stop postgresql.service

- Move the db data directory to olddata. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PostgreSQL#Upgrading_PostgreSQL

> sudo mv /var/lib/postgres/data /var/lib/postgres/olddata

- create new data directory and assign it to postgres user

> sudo mkdir /var/lib/postgres/data /var/lib/postgres/tmp
> sudo chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgres/data /var/lib/postgres/tmp

- install new version of Postgres including postgresql-old-upgrade
- get into postgres user and tmp directory

> sudo -i -u postgres
> [postgres]$ cd /var/lib/postgres/tmp

- initialize new db as

> [postgres]$ initdb -D /var/lib/postgres/data --locale=C.UTF-8 --encoding=UTF8

- start systmctl service from my user

> sudo systemctl start postgresql.service

- update h3 from postgres account

> pgxn install h3

- rebuild libraries from pacman: gdal, postgis, postgis-old-upgrade, pgsql-ogr-fdw
- stop systmctl service from my user

> sudo systemctl stop postgresql.service

- run pg_upgrade changing value to old version using the postgres account

> [postgres]$ pg_upgrade -b /opt/pgsql-PG_VERSION/bin -B /usr/bin -d
> /var/lib/postgres/olddata -D /var/lib/postgres/data

- check db is fine and remove tmp and olddata directories